# How to use str.contains to identify a word within column values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, contains

currently in my data I have a column that contains description of transaction. I want to use str.contains to identify which values/rows are AW (the fast food store) transaction. However, when I use `data['cat_desc'].str.contains('AW', case=False, na=False)`, it also identifies values that have string 'aw', for example 'awxxxx' but I don't want that. How can I just identify 'AW' as a word and not string? Thanks!

Comment: It will probably involve writing a regular expression, which is why it is suggested to provide several examples of your actual data, so that we could help demonstrate a solution that is useful for your data.

Comment: Please show us what the strings look like.

Comment: `data['cat_desc'].str.contains('\bAW\b', case=False, na=False)`

Comment: please refer to the following guidelines from stackoverflow  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use a regex with word boundaries (`'\b'`):

```
data['cat_desc'].str.contains(r'\bAW\b', case=False, na=False, regex=True)
```

*NB. By default [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) uses `regex=True`.*

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

x = "awxxx"
y = "aw"

a = bool(re.match(r"^aw$", x))
b = bool(re.match(r"^aw$", y))

print(a, b)
```